Trouble with combinatorial geometry
Suppose that the figure at right consists of thirty rods of equal length that form twelve pentagonal figures of equal size, which form the twelve sides of a regular dodecahedron. If any two rods are painted white and the remaining twenty-eight are painted black, how many distinct patterns are possible? Image

What have you tried?

Up to what symmetries?

I haven't tried anything yet as of now, I'm completely unsure of how to go about this and the questions seems a little open ended and up to interpretation.
If I had to guess how to do this I would calculate the total number of ways to choose 2 rods out of 30, which is 435, then use Burnside's Lemma to account for the dodecahedron's 60 rotational symmetries by summing the fixed colorings for each symmetry operation and dividing by 60 to find the number of distinct patterns.

Basic remarks : fix one white rod and place the second one in all positions with respect to the first one up to rotations (what about symmetries ?). Don't forget to divide (approx. !) by 2 the result you will obtain.
